# YAML BadConversion exception on vectors deserialization

Tags: c++, yaml

I'm using YAML to serialize a node editor I'm doing. In the YAML file, I store the information of the pins that the root node has by using YAML maps and sequences, resulting in the next structure in the YAML file:

```
MainRootNode:
        ID: 1395587317
        Name: Main Node
        Type: 1
        InputPins:
          - Pin: 1352419211
            Name: Vertex Position (Vec3)
            DataType: 4
            Value: vec4(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
            AllowsMultipleTypes: false
            DefValue: vec4(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
          - Pin: 1289745580
            Name: Vertex Normal (Vec3)
            DataType: 4
            Value: vec4(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
            AllowsMultipleTypes: false
            DefValue: vec4(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
            //... And so on
```

The issue comes when I try to deserialize the vec4 values, YAML throws a BadConversion exception. The values are serialized as follows (inside YAML namespace):

```
// --- Header dec ---
template<>
struct convert<glm::vec4>{ static Node encode(const glm::vec4& vec); };

// --- Cpp def ---
Node convert<glm::vec4>::encode(const glm::vec4& vec)
{
    Node node;
    node.push_back(vec.x);
    node.push_back(vec.y);
    node.push_back(vec.z);
    node.push_back(vec.w);
    node.SetStyle(EmitterStyle::Flow);
    return node;
}
```

Then, to deserialize them, I've made the next function:

```
// --- Header dec ---
template<>
struct convert<glm::vec4>{ static bool decode(const Node& node, glm::vec4& vec); };

// --- Cpp def ---
bool convert<glm::vec4>::decode(const Node& node, glm::vec4& vec)
{
    if (!node.IsSequence() || node.size() != 4)
        return false;

    vec.x = node[0].as<float>();
    vec.y = node[1].as<float>();
    vec.z = node[2].as<float>();
    vec.w = node[3].as<float>();
    return true;
}
```

And, debugging, I realized that the function returns false because that node is not a sequence and its size is 0. I've been searching for the origin of this problem and I can't manage to find it, does anybody sees something wrong?

The code to input a vector into a YAML Emitter would be the next:

```
YAML::Emitter& operator<<(YAML::Emitter& output, const glm::vec4& vec)
{
    output << YAML::Flow;
    output << YAML::BeginSeq << vec.x << vec.y << vec.z << vec.w << YAML::EndSeq;
    return output;
}
```

Also, I'm using this strategy to deserialize scene objects and it works fine but with the difference that, for some reason, it stores the vecs as `[x, y, z]` instead of `vec3(x, y, z)` (like in the nodes file), which I don't know if has something to do with the problem I'm having.

Comment: `[x, y, z]` is a YAML sequence, `vec3(x, y, z)` is a YAML scalar (loads into a single string). Don't expect a syntax you made up to have some special meaning in YAML.

Comment: Yes, but both are using the same function to serialize... What should I do different?

Comment: Well what do you do currently? You don't show the YAML serialization code.

Comment: Oh, yes, I posted the function to serialize a vec4, for the case of a vec3 is the same but with vec3 and without the "w" parameter stored.

Comment: What you posted is the function to *deserialize* a vec4, not to serialize it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... I'll edit the question to include the serialization function

Comment: So your actual problem is that your serialization code *should* output a YAML sequence but does not in some cases? You should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I just discovered I was including incorrectly the header in which I wrote the operators to input values into the YAML::Emitter, so YAML didn't knew that they had to be stored as I indicated... I hate to have this errors, sorry. The issue was solved by including the mentioned headers before the YAML includes in the files in which I serialized/deserialized.

Answer (score 1):

Your yaml file isn't valid in that sense. If you want to use that value like this:

```
Value: vec4(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
```

Then you will need to first get the node as a string

```
Node["value"].as<std::string>();
```

Then you need to write your own parser with substrings and convert the strings of the values to floats.

Alternatively you can use valid yaml for the values, which I think would save you a lot of work and pain. An example:

```
Value:
    - 0.000000
    - 0.000000
    - 0.000000
    - 0.000000
```

Then parsing it could be like:

```
Node["Value"].as<std::vector<float>>();
```

And then you can use the array as you did for the values.